# Record video stream with ffmpeg as a service

Tags: linux, video, ffmpeg, service, systemd

I would like to use ffmpeg to record the video stream of a surveillance camera. For this I have a script to start the recording and a service for systemd. The idea is that if ffmpeg is stopped in between because the stream is interrupted, the service will be restarted automatically.

Start recording (/media/HDD1/video/video-record.sh):

```
#!/bin/bash
ip=$1
codec=h264
res=1920x1080
out="/media/HDD1/video/$ip-$codec-$(date -u +"%Y%m%dT%H%M%S").mp4"
url="rtsp://192.168.4.$ip/axis-media/media.amp?camera=1&videocodec=$codec&fps=24&resolution=$res&compression=60&videozstrength=50&videoframeskipmode=drop"
ffmpeg -nostdin -i "$url" -acodec copy -vcodec copy $out
```

Service file:

```
[Unit]
Description=Record camera 101 to HDD

[Service]
Type=simple
ExecStart=/bin/bash /media/HDD1/video/video-record.sh 101
Restart=always
TimeoutStopSec=5

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

The script works fine when I start and stop it manually. Starting the service also works without problems, only when terminating there are problems. In the log it says:

```
Error closing file /media/HDD1/video/101-h264-20230719T094514.mp4: Immediate exit requested.
```

Also, I can't play the video file anymore. Any idea?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because as the systemd tag states: systemd questions should be for *programming questions* using systemd or its libraries. Questions about *configuring the daemon* (including writing unit files) are better directed to Unix & Linux: https://unix.stackexchange.com. Please delete this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The log entry is indicating that FFmpeg was killed with `SIGTERM`, causing it to ungracefully exit.  Your MP4 isn't playable because it is missing the `moov` atom which is written after the recording is successful.

You can configure Systemd's kill procedure to allow FFmpeg to exit gracefully by using `SIGINT` instead.  Try something like this:

```
KillSignal=SIGINT
```

See also:  https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.kill.html

Comment: Thank you very much! I had not come up with that idea.